# Yii2 renderAjax nested Listview

Tags: php, ajax, listview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to render the listview by ajax but it is giving me the following error:

```
Exception (Invalid Configuration) &#039;yii\base\InvalidConfigException&#039; with message &#039
;The &quot;dataProvider&quot; property must be set.
```

**Controller:**

```
public function actionLoadListviewAjax()
{
     $dataProvider = // call to a function which returns ArrayDataProvider
     return $this->renderAjax('myview', [ 'dataProvider' => $dataProvider ]);
}
```

**View:**

```
echo ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemView'     => 'items',
        'options' => ['class' => 'list-view-post'],
        'summary' => '',
        'emptyText' => '', 
    ]);
```

**$dataProvder:**

```
<pre>yii\data\ArrayDataProvider Object
(
    [key] => 
    [allModels] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [RecommendationCategory] => 
                    [ID] => 37
                    [GUID] => 
                    [Title] => test
                    [WallPostTypeID] => 1
                    [RecommendationCategoryID] => 0
                    [CommentsJSON] => 
                    [TotalComments] => 
                    [PostedMessage] => test
                    [FirstName] => test
                    [LastName] => test
                    [ProfileImagePath] => Lighthouse.jpg
                    [AddedOn] => 2015-07-18 15:14:06
                    [ImagePath] => 
                    [CommentProfileImagePath] => 
                    [IsSubscribe] => 1
                )

        )

    [id] => 
    [_sort:yii\data\BaseDataProvider:private] => 
    [_pagination:yii\data\BaseDataProvider:private] => 
    [_keys:yii\data\BaseDataProvider:private] => 
    [_models:yii\data\BaseDataProvider:private] => 
    [_totalCount:yii\data\BaseDataProvider:private] => 
    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
)
```

I tried renderPartial also but still the same error. Any ideas why it is giving the exeption?

**Update:**

In my itemView file `items` I have another listview for which it is giving the exception.

Answer (score 1):

actually list view item does not have to access to external variables that has been sent through widget.
however if you have to use `$dataProvider` variable in your inner view file try to use callable to display items in your list view.

something like this:

```

```
echo ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView'     => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        return $this->renderAjax('items', [
            'dataProvider' => $widget->dataProvider,
        ]);
    },
    'options' => ['class' => 'list-view-post'],
    'summary' => '',
    'emptyText' => '', 
]);
```

```

more info here

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html#$itemView-detail